# How to add filters to the "Browse Material to be linked" popup?

Tags: python, materials, customization

I would like to use a UI component similar to the "Browse Material to be liked" (located in the Materials panel) in a script but a bit customized.

[image: Browse Material to be linked ui component]

I found how to use this one:

```
row.template_ID(ob, "active_material", new="material.new", live_icon=True)
```

But I cannot find the source code. I would like to add more filters on it than just the text filter.
I've tried with uiLists but they do not assign the selected item directly to the material slot.

Can you help me and tell me how to reproduce that Browse Material component ? Or where to find the code of the template that is used here?

Thank you